# Python multiprocessing - accessing shared file by parallel processes

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, locking, file-sharing

Let's assume that I have a Python function func() that is running in parallel by several processes in Python, this function calls three functions x(),y() and z().

x(): Writes some data inside a file called f based on its inputs.

y(): have nothing to do with file f.

z(): reads the data written in file f and then does its functionality.

In order to avoid conflicts between different processes writing and reading into/from file f, I thought about locking the file f in function x() and unlocking it in z(). By doing so I would guarantee that the data written in f by x() is read by z() within the same process and it is not overwritten by other parallel processes accessing the file.
as following:

```
import fcntl

def x():
    with open("f", "w") as file:
        # Acquire an exclusive lock on the file
        fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        # Write to the file
        file.write("Hello from x()\n")

def y():
    # Do something that doesn't require access to file f
    print("Hello from y()")

def z():
    with open("f", "r") as file:
        # Read from the file
        data = file.read()
        print("Hello from z():", data)
        # Release the lock on the file created by x()
        fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

My question is: is it valid to lock a file in a function and then unlock it in another function running by the same process and if so?

Comment: I would recommend using while loops to access the files, you can put error handling in, to hang and wait until available if another process is reading it.